# How do i get all ui elements of a view? (Web Dynpro ABAP)

Tags: abap, webdynpro

I want to make the labels of an input field invisible when the input field is invisible.
I cant bind it to the same context because they are build dynamically.

Is there a way to get all view elements so i can loop over them and make the label invisible dynamically?

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail why you can't bind to a context element? I can't imagine any concrete example -- even when constructing either context or UI manually -- where it wouldn't be possible to bind the label and input field properties to the same context element.

Comment: Is this because you are building a table? As @vwegert says, we need more context.

Comment: The context is build dynamically based on a z table.. so i just want to loop over the ui elements of the view. Is it possible?

Comment: Its weird that i cant find any method to loop over all view elements

Comment: @vikdb Does "Loop at screen" not work in your case?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: This is Web Dynpro, not classical Dynpro programming.

Comment: @vikdb If you create the context dynamically, you also have to create the UI dynamically. That would be the point to create the bindings dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example action handler code which finds the label `MYLABEL` inside a container and hides it. It doesn't completely cover your use case, but I think it will get you started.

```
data view type ref to cl_wdr_view.
view ?= wd_this->wd_get_api( ).
data container type ref to cl_wd_uielement_container.
container ?= view->root_element.
data children type cl_wd_uielement=>tt_uielement.
children = container->get_children( ).
data element type ref to cl_wd_uielement.
loop at children into element.
  data id type string.
  id = element->get_id( ).
  if id = `MYLABEL`.
    element->set_visible( `01` ).
  endif.
endloop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Each view controller contains the method WDDOMODIFYVIEW with an initially empty implementation. Inside this method you have access to the whole UI element hierarcy and should be able to retrieve references to both the label and the input field and hide the lable in case the input field is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

First, write a second program that will be responsible for calling your program using the SUBMIT ABAP instruction with the EXPORTING LIST TO MEMORY addition.

When you run this caller program it will call your program using the SUBIT, but instead of generating output on screen, system will send the output to system memory.

Later, in webdynpro or in any other program, you can call ABAP function LIST_FROM_MEMORY to retrieve your program's earlier output to an internal table.

Cheers!

Comment: please check your spelling